# Page with sub section using fullpage.js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I have created multiple page with fullpage.js script and it is nice plugin to work with. I have a scenario where where one page has multiple sub sections and i want anchor nav to link to relevant page and if page has multiple sub section then it shoudl scroll through those section and so on.

Just to simplify i have set up example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgXbWj

In this example when i click on First Section nav it goes to first section.. if i click on second section it goes to second section...

Now if i click on third section nav it take me to `Section Two sub page one` section while i want it to go to `Section Three` that is

How can i make it work in such scenario.

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Section One</div>
    <div class="section">Section Two</div>
         <div class="section">Section Two sub page one</div>
         <div class="section">Section Two sub page two</div>
    <div class="section">Section Three</div>
    <div class="section">Section Four</div>
</div>

<ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#page1">First section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#page2">Second section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#page3">Third section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#page4">Fourth section</a></li>
</ul>



$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
  menu: '#myMenu'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed To make it work.  working code. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRJOkb

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" data-anchor="one">Section One</div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="two">Section Two</div>
         <div class="section">Section Two sub page one</div>
         <div class="section">Section Two sub page two</div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="three">Section Three</div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="four">Section Four</div>
</div>

<ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#one">First section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#two">Second section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#three">Third section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#four">Fourth section</a></li>
</ul>

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['one', 'two', 'a1','a2','three', 'four'],
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange',  'orange', 'orange','#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
  menu: '#myMenu'
});
```